# How to change the color of dropdown item in iPad

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of the dropdown items in ipad but it seems not to be working.this is my code.

```
    select

 {
       background: url('/images/test.png') no-repeat right;
       background-color: #333;
       background-size: 16px 13px;
       background-position: 62px ;
       padding:6px;
       font-size: 14px;
       color: #ffffff;       
       border: 0;
 }
```

But the dropdown items are not changing to white color in iPad...any suggestions?

Comment: Want to change color of font in dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the appearance of selectbox items in iOS browsers.  iOS Safari doesn't listen to the styling you give it.  You would have to make your dropdowns in pure javascript to give them a different style.

Comment: Yes you cant change unless you create a custom one.

Comment: I discourage using a custom pure js solution. The select feature in IOS is nice. Very user friendly.